# verify digital signature

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

I want to verify my signature. I use this code

```
 var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
  byte[] bytesToVerify = encoder.GetBytes(LoginChallenge);
 RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
 RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = publickey1;
 rsa.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
  bool suc = rsa.VerifyData(bytesToVerify, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signedBytes);
```

I have public key in byte array format. It is in my db. like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A1l4.png)

always suc=false. I'm sure bytetoverify  has same value with input value in method sign.

my sign method:

```
 Signature signature=Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_RSA_SHA_PKCS1,false);
      signature.init(thePrivateKey,Signature.MODE_SIGN);
      signLength=signature.sign(buffer,(short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA & 0xFF), inputlength, buffer, (short)(0));

      apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0,signLength);
```

I dont know my generate public key in this way is problem or sign has problem. in sign method I use sh1 and pkcs1 but in verify i only find sh1.

can every body help me?

Comment: **Any** format is a byte array format if it is on your computer. You need to be more specific and show us what you tried. Showing all the bytes in hexadecimals would be a good idea; it's a *public* key, right?

Comment: Thank you for answer me. yes I saved public key in sql server as image. I want to fetch it ans convert it to rsa parameter. I can't see public key in db to show you because it is like image.and yes it is in hex format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you save into the database? Just the Modulus value?

An RSA public key has two fields, Modulus and Exponent.  They are both required to do a successful key import and operation.

In 99.999993% of the RSA keys ever created the Exponent value is `new byte[] { 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 }`; so you can *almost always* get away with storing just the Modulus value, and assuming what `Exponent` is.

For best results, don't assume.  Or, at the very least, reject keys on registration if their Exponent value isn't `0x010001`.

So really this comes down to:

- You need to set Exponent (to the correct value)
- You need to make sure your import logic matches your export logic, to ensure you're loading/saving the same things into the same places.

Comment: Thank youfor answer.I stored only module value in db